# how to mark a record type queryable in cloud kit programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, ckquery

Im having an issue with cloud-kit whenever I create a new CKRecordType programmatically. In the cloud kit dashboard this is the error message I get:[image]

The quick and easy fix would be to click the "Add ID Query Index" button and be done with it, however, I was wondering if there was a way you could accomplish this programmatically. The reason being is because when the app is deployed, the user will have the ability to create new record types and it would be a major hassle and a reck if I had to check cloud-kit every time a user decides to make a new record type.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you create new record types at runtime in production? I thought the schema had to be fixed in production.

Comment: * Im not familiar with that restriction but never the less I have created new records during run time so I would say no

Comment: But you've created then during development, right? Is your app in the app store yet? You need to read the first paragraph of the following: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/CreatingaSchemabySavingRecords/CreatingaSchemabySavingRecords.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH3-SW3

Comment: Also see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/DeployingYourCloudKitApp/DeployingYourCloudKitApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH10-SW2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In production you are not allowed to create new recordTypes. Besides that you can only add indexes from the dashboard on development.

Comment: Do you know if you are allowed to create new fields during production?